Analyse application audio with Python
I have some audio that's played from some applications (Firefox in my example), and I'd like to analyze it with Numpy.
I've came up with this code:
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
BUFFER = 1024

for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    info = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    if info['name'] == 'Firefox':
        break

stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=2,
    rate=int(info['defaultSampleRate']),
    input=True,
    input_device_index=info['index'],
    frames_per_buffer=BUFFER
)

while True:
    data = stream.read(BUFFER)
    audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    print(audio_data)

But I'm getting OSError: [Errno -9997] Invalid sample rate if I keep this default rate. If I switch to rate=44100, I'm getting a core dump:
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
[1]    576600 IOT instruction (core dumped)

What aspect of with my setup is flawed? How can I simply evaluate audio output from Linux application?

First off, if BUFFER is 1024 bytes, and a frame is 2 channels of 16 bits, then frames_per_buffer should be BUFFER/4.

Thank you for your comment, tried with frames_per_buffer=int(BUFFER/4) but same issue. I'm really not sure that pyaudio is able to listen to a software output
